# If R/I is a free R-module, then I = 0.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let I be an ideal of a commutative ring R.

> Prove or disprove: If R/I is a free R-module, then I = 0.

Need some hints. I know that a free R-module has a basis and is isomorphic to R$^n$ for some finite n.

If R/I is free R-module, why must it be isomorphic to R?

Comment: It is not clear whether you talk about *commutative ring*. If not, consider a ring $R$ with the property that $R \simeq R \times R$ as a ring.

Comment: @PavelČoupek I think you want a ring $R$ with the property that $R≃R×R$ as (say, left) $R$-modules, that is, a noncommutative ring which doesn't have the IBN property.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If a module is isomorphic to $R/I$ and $i\in I$, then multiplication by $i$ is the same as multiplication by $0$.  What acts as zero on a free module?

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean by your last question. Could u explain further?

Comment: I mean that what are the elements $r\in R$ such that $rm=0$ for all $m$ in your free module.  In different language, what is the annihilator of a free module?

Comment: What is the annihilator of $R/I$?

Comment: the annihilator of R/I is I